# create menu in php - pages in sub directories

Tags: php, navigation, subdirectory

I am learning PHP. I want to create a menu that can open pages from any folders in the site's directory. The following is the structure of the directories and files:

```
ROOT DIRECTORY
 dirINCLUDES
    header.php
    footer.php
    navigation.php

 dirPROJECT
    index.php
    project1.php
    project2.php

 index.php
```

The following is in my navigation.php:

```
<ul class="accordion"  id="accordion">
<li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
<li><a href="project/index.php">project</a></li>
</ul>
```

Right now when I click on the "project" link, it takes me to the project/index.php, but when I am on that page and click on the "home" link it doesn't take me to the home page.
I have included all the php files in the dir INCLUDES into the index.php and project/index.php files.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: just add a `/` to the beginning of your links href. a `/` references the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<ul class="accordion"  id="accordion"> <li><a href="../index.php">home</a></li> <li><a href="index.php">project</a></li> </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try full path like /index.php, /project/index.php etc

```
<li><a href="/mysite/index.php">home</a></li>
<li><a href="/mysite/project/index.php">project</a></li>
```

Edited links

Comment: this takes the file from the localhost, for example:   <li><a href="/project/index.php">project</a></li>
 will be the link to localhost/project/index.php   but the file is actually at localhost/mysite/project/index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
href="<?echo dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'directory/file.php';?>"
```

or

```
href="/directory/file.php"
```

Comment: With ur code, it gives the link like---- c:\wamp\www\mysite/project-select/index.php

Comment: you should not use dirname for HREF as it will give absolute path

Answer (score 0):

```
function menu($dir){
$files = glob($dir.'/*');
$html = '<ul>';
foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_dir($file)){
        $html .= menu($file);
    }else{
        $html .= '<li><a href="'. $file .'">'. basename($file,'.php') .'</a></li>';
    }
}
$html .= '</ul>';
return $html;
```

}

`echo menu("./*");`

Comment: this lists all the files from all the directories. I want to build the website navigation not show all the pages.